# Show that A=B when A,B are contained in M with d(A,B) <= 3/4

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let U be a non empty set and let M=the set of all subsets of U. Define the metric d on M by d(A,B)=|A("delta")B|.

I'm having trouble knowing where to start with this. I know all of the requirements for it to be a metric but this is different compared to anything my teacher has showed me

Comment: The Delta is the triangle thing. Like the operator or whatever its called

Answer (score 1):

Our distance function only takes on non-negative **integer** values. So if $d(A,B)\le \frac{3}{4}$, then $d(A,B)=0$. And it is easy to verify that the distance between two sets is $0$ precisely if the sets are equal. For $A\Delta B=\emptyset$ if and only if $A=B$.

Comment: So its really that easy? Thought for sure I was missing something...

Comment: If the problem is correctly stated, then it is that easy.

Comment: But what about the |A (delta) B| part? Isn't that normally supposed to be |A-B| ?

Comment: $A\Delta B$ is the *symmetric difference* between $A$ and $B$. We can express it in terms of set difference as $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$.  Informally, the stuff that's in $A$ or $B$ but not in both.

Comment: Oh OK so that's basically |A-B|U|B-A|?

Comment: Yes, I am using $X\setminus Y$ where you use $X-Y$.  Same meaning.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Correction to your comment. I see now that you wrote $|A-B|\cup |B-A|$. That is not quite right, $|A-B|$ usually denotes the cardinality (size) of $A-B$, and you can't "union" sizes. It would be correct to say that $|A\Delta B|=|A\setminus B|+|B\setminus A|$.